# Java: Convert from Scanner utility to JOptionPane

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, joptionpane

I started creating a Java program for my class. It didn't take long to make it using the Scanner utility to display the information in the console, so I decided I would try to make it utilize JOptionPane so it would display the information in the pop-up window (obviously). I can make it so it uses the JOptionPane, but right after you input the number in the JOptionPane window, it asks you to input it in the console. I've seen questions asking for people to convert their programs for them, but that is not what I want. I just want some hints, so I can do it myself.

I want to know how to get rid of the part that makes it so you have to enter in the numbers in the console, so you only use the JOptionPane. Any help is welcome. I know the program doesn't do exactly as it is expected to do now, but I can figure that part out once I get where I want to first. Thank you!

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JDialog;


public class Program4
{

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
    int product = 0;
    double product1;
    double product2;
    double product3;
    double product4;
    double product5;
    int quantity;
    String done = "y";
  int selection;
  boolean isNo;
    double totalSales = 0;

    while (done.equals("y"))
    {
        JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,
     "Enter product number: ", "Product Number ", 
     JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
        product=input.nextInt();

        JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, 
     "Enter how many were sold: ", "Product Quantity ", 
     JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
        quantity= input.nextInt();



   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
   "Total Sales $" + totalSales);



        switch (product)
        {
            case 1: product1 = 2.98;
                    totalSales+=(2.98*quantity);
                    break;
            case 2: product2 = 4.50;
                    totalSales+=(4.50*quantity);
                     break;
            case 3: product3 = 9.98;
                    totalSales+=(9.98*quantity);
                    break;
            case 4: product4 = 4.49;
                    totalSales+=(4.49*quantity);
                    break;
            case 5: product5 = 6.87;
                    totalSales+=(6.87*quantity);
                    break;
        }

        selection = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, 
     "Any other products?" );
     isNo = (selection == JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
     done = input.next();
    }
    System.out.println(totalSales);

  }
}
```

Comment: What would the UI look like (eg. what type of controls)? Write it. Then it's just a matter of getting the data from the UI (and whatever controls were used) before using it in the calculations. It may be preferable to start with a ["Swing Tutorial"](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/) to get the basic UI components and access down.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, you showed the dialog and then you did nothing with the input and you asked the user to enter it again.

```
JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,
 "Enter product number: ", "Product Number ", 
 JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
    product=input.nextInt();
```

The call to `showInputDialog` in fact returns the user input but you ignored it. Instead, you call `input.nextInt ()` which scans the console. So that's why the input dialog shows up and you need to enter your input in the console.

Thus, you should not instantiate the `Scanner` object at all. Just call:

```
String inputStr = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter product number: ", "Product Number ", 
JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
```

Now you have an input string. But you want an `int` to go in your `product` variable. So you call:

```
product = Integer.parseInt (inputStr);
```

If you don't understand, ask me in the comments!

Answer (score 0):

So a `JOptionPane.showInputDialog` returns the string that the user enters. This would take the place of the scanner. Use the string returned from the `JOptionPane`.

```
String inputValue = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please input a value");
```